# What is oflag in dd?

Tags: command-line, dd

What is `oflag` for in the `dd` command?

What are the options `oflag=`?

Currently I am doing `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4096`

To wipe out a disk.

Comment: `info dd` has a pretty good explanation for this. If you don't understand any of this, you may ask a specific question to what you don't understand of it.

Answer (score 5):

Taken straight from `info dd`

(note: this was taken from a [Lubuntu] 20.04 box; so it may contain flags that don't exist in your version, so you're better use `info dd` on your own box to see exactly what is available for your system)

> oflag=FLAG[,FLAG]...’
>        Access the output file using the flags specified by the FLAG
>        argument(s).  (No spaces around any comma(s).)
>
> ```
>  Here are the flags.  Not every flag is supported on every operating
>  system.
>
>  ‘append’
>       Write in append mode, so that even if some other process is
>       writing to this file, every ‘dd’ write will append to the
>       current contents of the file.  This flag makes sense only for
>       output.  If you combine this flag with the ‘of=FILE’ operand,
>       you should also specify ‘conv=notrunc’ unless you want the
>       output file to be truncated before being appended to.
>
>  ‘cio’
>       Use concurrent I/O mode for data.  This mode performs direct
>       I/O and drops the POSIX requirement to serialize all I/O to
>       the same file.  A file cannot be opened in CIO mode and with a
>       standard open at the same time.
>
>  ‘direct’
>       Use direct I/O for data, avoiding the buffer cache.  Note that
>       the kernel may impose restrictions on read or write buffer
>       sizes.  For example, with an ext4 destination file system and
>       a Linux-based kernel, using ‘oflag=direct’ will cause writes
>       to fail with ‘EINVAL’ if the output buffer size is not a
>       multiple of 512.
>
>  ‘directory’
>
>       Fail unless the file is a directory.  Most operating systems
>       do not allow I/O to a directory, so this flag has limited
>       utility.
>
>  ‘dsync’
>       Use synchronized I/O for data.  For the output file, this
>       forces a physical write of output data on each write.  For the
>       input file, this flag can matter when reading from a remote
>       file that has been written to synchronously by some other
>       process.  Metadata (e.g., last-access and last-modified time)
>       is not necessarily synchronized.
>
>  ‘sync’
>       Use synchronized I/O for both data and metadata.
>
>  ‘nocache’
>       Request to discard the system data cache for a file.  When
>       count=0 all cached data for the file is specified, otherwise
>       the cache is dropped for the processed portion of the file.
>       Also when count=0, failure to discard the cache is diagnosed
>       and reflected in the exit status.
>
>       Note data that is not already persisted to storage will not be
>       discarded from cache, so note the use of the “sync” options in
>       the examples below, which are used to maximize the
>       effectiveness of the ‘nocache’ flag.
>
>       Here are some usage examples:
>
>            # Advise to drop cache for whole file
>            dd if=ifile iflag=nocache count=0
>
>            # Ensure drop cache for the whole file
>            dd of=ofile oflag=nocache conv=notrunc,fdatasync count=0
>
>            # Advise to drop cache for part of file
>            # Note the kernel will only consider complete and
>            # already persisted pages.
>            dd if=ifile iflag=nocache skip=10 count=10 of=/dev/null
>
>            # Stream data using just the read-ahead cache.
>            # See also the ‘direct’ flag.
>            dd if=ifile of=ofile iflag=nocache oflag=nocache,sync
>
>  ‘nonblock’
>       Use non-blocking I/O.
>
>  ‘noatime’
>       Do not update the file’s access timestamp.  *Note File
>       timestamps::.  Some older file systems silently ignore this
>       flag, so it is a good idea to test it on your files before
>       relying on it.
>
>  ‘noctty’
>       Do not assign the file to be a controlling terminal for ‘dd’.
>       This has no effect when the file is not a terminal.  On many
>       hosts (e.g., GNU/Linux hosts), this option has no effect at
>       all.
>
>  ‘nofollow’
>       Do not follow symbolic links.
>
>  ‘nolinks’
>       Fail if the file has multiple hard links.
>
>  ‘binary’
>       Use binary I/O.  This option has an effect only on nonstandard
>       platforms that distinguish binary from text I/O.
>
>  ‘text’
>       Use text I/O.  Like ‘binary’, this option has no effect on
>       standard platforms.
>
>  ‘fullblock’
>       Accumulate full blocks from input.  The ‘read’ system call may
>       return early if a full block is not available.  When that
>       happens, continue calling ‘read’ to fill the remainder of the
>       block.  This flag can be used only with ‘iflag’.  This flag is
>       useful with pipes for example as they may return short reads.
>       In that case, this flag is needed to ensure that a ‘count=’
>       argument is interpreted as a block count rather than a count
>       of read operations.
>
>  ‘count_bytes’
>       Interpret the ‘count=’ operand as a byte count, rather than a
>       block count, which allows specifying a length that is not a
>       multiple of the I/O block size.  This flag can be used only
>       with ‘iflag’.
>
>  ‘skip_bytes’
>       Interpret the ‘skip=’ operand as a byte count, rather than a
>       block count, which allows specifying an offset that is not a
>       multiple of the I/O block size.  This flag can be used only
>       with ‘iflag’.
>
>  ‘seek_bytes’
>       Interpret the ‘seek=’ operand as a byte count, rather than a
>       block count, which allows specifying an offset that is not a
>       multiple of the I/O block size.  This flag can be used only
>       with ‘oflag’.
>
>  These flags are not supported on all systems, and ‘dd’ rejects
>  attempts to use them when they are not supported.  When reading
>  from standard input or writing to standard output, the ‘nofollow’
>  and ‘noctty’ flags should not be specified, and the other flags
>  (e.g., ‘nonblock’) can affect how other processes behave with the
>  affected file descriptors, even after ‘dd’ exits.
> ```

*`man dd` would provide the quick manual.reference.page information, for many complex commands you can use `info` to view other pages.*